# Disabling Mouse-hover-color-change for the apex:pageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, pageblocktable

I am displaying a PageBlockTable with 12 records from a Custom object. And each `<apex:column>` has its own color code rendered based on the value.

```
<apex:column headerValue="Field One" width="4%"
             styleClass="{!CASE(a.Field1__c, 'Red', 'red', 'Green', 'green', 'Yellow', 'yellow', 'white')}">
    <apex:outputText >{!a.Field1__c}</apex:outputText>
</apex:column>
```

But, when my mouse pointer hover on any of the rows, it disables all the colors and show a plain white row. But, I want the row to stay how it rendered(different color codes to each table data). Is there any `Boolean` variable I need to make `false` or other attributes to add/change?

Comment: This is more of a CSS question than a VF question, I think

Comment: I see this: `<tr class="dataRow even  first highlight .....`  when I mouse hover on any of the rows. It changes dynamically. How can I get a hold of it? How to make it not to switch between highlight and non-highlight?

Comment: You can't change the default SFDC stylesheets... but you can override them. Ergo, a CSS issue. :)

Comment: Seems simple, but as this `highlight` keeps on changing dynamically on my mouse movement, I cannot inspect the right attribute. :(

Comment: Use the Chrome console to add it manually

Answer (score 6):

You can't "disable" it, but apparently you can countermand it. I've come up with two potential solutions.

## !important

Use an important style.

```
<style>
.red, .red.highlight {
    background: red !important;
}
</style>
```

This will override the Salesforce style sheet.

## Toggle "highlight"

You can also remove the class as its added:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable onrowmouseover="this.classList.remove('highlight')" ...
```

`onRowMouseOver` is called after the library does its stuff, and so you'll undo the highlight that it does. There's no noticeable flicker because browsers delay rendering until the end of a JavaScript execution cycle.